# My blog has lots of types of content. What's the best way to organize it for readers to discover its depth?

Tags: categorization, tag-cloud

Right now I have it organized with 4 or 5 categories at the top (how-to, trends, etc.). But if someone comes to the site through a social media link or search keyword (which is typical) she may not realize just *how much* we have written about, say, security or storage technologies.

I still love tag clouds, but I'm told that's outdated. What's the current thought on surfacing content categories?

Comment: Look to your right for examples ---->

Answer (score 1):

You're faced with the same problem just about every site has. Take a careful, exacting look at a lot of sites: CNN, Mashable, Amazon, BestBuy, Home Depot, Khan Academy (and on and on and on). You'll see that each are faced with a similar problem and solve it in different ways - some better than others.

Again -- the problem you're facing is there for just about every information and eCommerce site.

Look at them and you'll see navigation and display patterns.